# How can I show a timecode while playing audio in FFPlay?

Tags: command-line, sound, xorg, ffmpeg

I'm wanting to play strictly audio files with FFplay.
Already when opening files it displays a window with a rolling spectogram.

I'd like to have the same spectogram with an overlay of a timecode in hh:mm:ss.

There is nothing on the man page whatsoever of this.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the [showspectrum](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#showspectrum) and [drawtext](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext) filters.

[image]

```
ffplay -f lavfi "amovie=input.mp3,asplit[a][out1];[a]showspectrum=mode=separate:color=intensity:slide=1,drawtext=text='%{pts\:hms}':box=1:boxborderw=5:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=h-(text_h*2):fontsize=16:font=Mono[out0]"
```

- Seeking during playback will not be possible.
- Use a mono font, otherwise the width of the numbers will vary causing movement. The use of the option `font=Mono` allows you to set the font family, but this requires your `ffmpeg` to be compiled with `--enable-libfribidi`. Otherwise, use the `fontfile` option and provide the full path to the font file.